# Rogulock: Pact Of Chain and Sneak Attack

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars, sneak-attack, invisibility, helping

I am building a rogue-warlock multiclass in 5e DnD and I have a question. I am using Pact of the Chain and I chose an imp familiar. If I remember correctly, an imp can cast Invisiblity infinitly. And It can use help action in its turn. And Rogues get sneak attack if it has allies within five feet of the target.

So can I send my imp (who will be invisible all the time) near my enemy and let it do the Help action in each of its turns?

And on every one of my turns, do I get a free sneak attack with advantage.?

Comment: I think this question has been answered fully across a couple of questions on the site, I've added several targets to the dupe list.

Comment: If you don't think these answer your question, please let us know what's missing and we may be able to reopen. Hopefully, they do help!